# Do you need to be a customer of the bank to use their safety deposit box services?

Tags: united-states, banking, safe-deposit-box

The bank I want to use in the future doesn't have physical bank office locations so I'm looking into being able to use a safety deposit box service or something similar to store some documents.

Comment: If you use a bank's safety deposit box, doesn't that make you a customer?

Comment: I don't understand --  If they don't have physical bank office locations, where would these safety deposit boxes would be located?

Answer (score 7):

Forgive me Miles, I see you are new here. In general, we need a standard answer "ask the business." This question falls into that category. Why? Because even if ten of us agree on the answer, but some bank takes the opposite position, that doesn't help you. You need to go to the convenient brick and mortar bank near you and ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know every bank is different, but I'm looking to hear a general experience from the community. I'd at least like to know that it's not something that is unheard of.

Comment: Have you called/visited your local B&M bank?

Comment: Some may require you to open a small savings account for $5. Now you are a customer. Add $1 every year to make sure the account isn't considered abandoned.

Comment: Thanks mhoran. Could you make that an answer so you get answer points please?